# Having difficulty defining conditions to call certain functions and error messages

Tags: bash, shell, unix, vi

I'm writing a piece of code which will use data from a file that I've already made in order to work out the average value of the file, the minimum value, maximum value and then finally displaying all values at once.
I'm very new to unix so I'm trying to learn it but I just cant seem to crack where I need to go with my code in order for it to gain functionality.
I've got the basics of the code but I need to find a way to call the functions using the year, which is stored in a directory corresponding to that year which is making me think I'm going to have problems calling from the file as I'm using a sed function to only take line 4 of that file rather than the year.
I also need to figure out how to set error messages and status to the script if they have not stated (Year) (One of the 4 commands), the year doesnt correspond to one available in the tree and the keyword is invalid.
Any help or even pointers towards good material to learn these things would be great.
Here is my current code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#getalldata() {
#find . -name "ff_*" -exec  sed -n '4p' {} \;
#}

#Defining where the population configuration file is which contains all the data
popconfile.txt=$HOME/testarea


#Function to find the average population of all of the files
averagePopulation()
{
total=0
list=$(cat popconfile.txt)
for var in "${list[@]}"
do
    total=$((total + var))
done

average=$((total/$(wc -l popconfile.txt)))
echo "$average"
}

#Function to find the maximum population from all the files
maximumPopulation()
{
max=1

for in `cat popconfile.txt`
do
if [[ $1 > "$max" ]]; then
max=$1
echo "$max"
fi
done
}

#Function to find the minimum population from all the files
minimumPopulation()
{
min=1000000
for in `cat popconfile.txt`
do
if [[ $1 < "$min" ]]; then
max=$1
echo "$min"
fi
done
}

#Function to show all of the results in one place
function showAll()
{
echo "$min"
echo "$max"
echo "$average"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Strange, my code is exactly the same for min and it is for max but it still says my max has syntax error, thanks for the site though that looks super useful

Comment: Use `-gt` and `-lt` for numerical comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your popconfile.txt format is

```
    cat popconfile.txt
    150
    10
    45
    1000
    34
    87
```

You might be able to simplify your code with :

```
    for i in $(cat popconfile.txt);do
            temp[$i]=$i
    done

    pop=(${temp[*]})

    min=${pop[0]}
    max=${pop[$((${#pop[*]}-1))]}

    for ((j=0;j<${#pop[*]};j++));do
                    sum=$(($sum+${pop[$j]}))
    done

    average=$(($sum/${#pop[*]}))

    echo "maximum="$max
    echo "minimum="$min
    echo "average="$average
```

Be aware though that the average here or in your code is calculated with integer mathematics, so you're loosing all decimals.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what my con file looks like since in theory all i did was cut the 4th line out of every file in the directory and then output it into this file. I only actually need integers since there are only whole numbers in the file thankfully! Your version looks much cleaner, only issue I can see is the idea of these functions in my code is so that a user can use the command myStats 2000 average to find the average number in the 2000 directory, will merging these functions together effect that functionality?

Comment: First, average of whole numbers won't always give you whole numbers. If you have 1 and 5, average is 2.5. Second, you can always modify that code to be used in functions, it's only an example based on your code of how it can be done. By the way, for you average function, instead of using wc -l .... you should use ${#list[*]}.

Comment: Actually I overlooked that entirely, I'll have to find a way to incorporate a way to either round the total or use decimals. Think im going to spend tonight working out how to call functions based on commands entered and how to select directories with these functions then solve that once I can atleast call the things I need properly. Thanks for the help! Can never appreciate help enough when learning a language! :)